# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. Settings of ServicePointManager doesn't fix

Tags: c#, .net, web

I get that exception when I try download string using WebClient. 
I tried many cases to setup ServicePointManager:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue: true and false
```

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol: SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

and

```cs
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

and

```
(SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12)
```

and all Tls 
and all protocols.
Every combination was used. Not working.
But if I use curl command - I'm getting json well.

```
curl -X GET https://myurl/2019-05-29
```

Same behavior from browser
System: *Windows Server 2012 R2*
.NET: *Framework 4.6.1*

**Callstack**:
`Failed to get fixtures from URI=https://myurl/2019-05-29.  System.Net.WebException: 
An exception occurred during a WebClient request. --->System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)`

Code with one case:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
              (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
       var json = wc.DownloadString(uri);
       return json;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant, server doesn't use any anti-malware products

Comment: @HansPassant, the machine which uses that code is client. From that machine I can get data via _curl_ command, but WebClient throws exception. Unfortunatelly, I don't have access to server